# How to make a search function? (Replace something with what people search for)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function

This is my current code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE namn = 'Jargon'"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
  { 
  echo "<div class='content_left'>"; 
  echo "<div class='blue_text_header'>Information</div>"; 
  echo "<h1>"; 
  echo $row['Namn']; 
  echo "</h1>"; 

  echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />"; 
  echo "<div class='red_text_header'>Obekräftade fall</div>"; 
  echo str_replace(',','<br />', $row['unconfirmed']); 

  echo "</div>"; 
  echo "<div class='content_right'>"; 

  echo "<div class='orange_text_header'>Andra namn</div>"; 
  echo str_replace(',','<br />', $row['Alias']); 

  echo "<br />"; 
  echo "<br /><br /><br /><br />"; 

  echo "<div class='green_text_header'>Bekräftade fall</div>"; 
  echo str_replace(',','<br />', $row['confirmed']); 
  } 

mysql_close($con);
```

and as you see, it is the "`SELECT * FROM characters WHERE namn = 'Jargon'`" that chooses what information to output and I want the users do decide what should be output, so I want like a simple search form, and if people write like "hello" I want the "Jargon" to be switched with hello, if u get it?

And if you can, can you make me both the search form and the post.php file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your first line to these:

```
if (!isset($_GET['name']) { // Handle a missing name variable in some way 
    // (if you like you can even include the form on this page itself, allowing 
    //  the page to submit data back to itself, with this isset() check
    //  determining whether to show the form or process the form)
    print "You must enter a name";
    exit;
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE namn = '".mysql_real_escape_string($name)."'");
```

...and add such a form:

```
<form action="post.php" method="get">
<label for="name">Name</label><input name="name" id="name"/>
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$input_clean = mysql_real_escape_string($input);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE namn LIKE '%$input_clean%'");
```

If $input = "hello", you will get results like "hello", "hello world", "I said hello", etc, but you wont get something like "hi bob". Combine that with brettz9's answer about the HTML form and you got yourself a searching program.

Comment: Though I didn't see his example as implying that kind of search, +1 for anticipating a possible meaning of "search"

Answer (score 0):

You would want to build the query string dynamically, e.g. using `mysql_query(sprintf("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE namn = '%s'",mysql_real_escape_string($myInputVar)));` to build your query. Just make sure you're properly escaping the input provided by the user with `mysql_escape_string` so you aren't opening yourself up to SQL injection attacks!

Comment: +1 for your explanation on injection and sprintf, though it is not strictly needed here, can make things better structured--but maybe too much for someone new at it.

Comment: Yeah, you need mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: Corrected mysql_escape_string to mysql_real_escape_string. Agreed that sprintf isn't strictly necessary in this case, but often makes things easier for future modifications.